# Doctrine 1.4 populate collection with relations using fromArray()

Tags: doctrine

I performed a raw SQL query in Doctrine 1.4 (in order to acheve advanced subqueries) and obtained a joined resultset with data from different tables (Evaluation and User):

(this is what I have in the array $all:)

```
id  user_id guide_id    group_id    level   date    score   max_score   last_improvement    total_improvement   created_at  updated_at  email   password    salt    first_name  last_name   is_active   is_super_admin  last_login  verified_email  entity_type entity_name country_id  state_id    source  raw preferences evaluation_count
52  52  2   2001    1   2014-06-19  245 245         2014-05-19 16:24:31 2014-08-08 17:13:20 martin@mindset3.com 040000000000000secret0000b  4da00nothingtoseehere067c   Martín (municipio)  1   1       1   municipio   Martincipio 0                                               0   12              17
52  52  2   2002    1   2014-06-26  122 170 -48 -48 2014-05-19 16:24:31 2014-08-08 17:13:20 martin@mindset3.com 0000000000000000000000009b  4d00000movealong000c0c67c   Martín (municipio)  1   1       1   municipio   Martincipio 0                                               0   12              17
```

So I did:

```
$ret = new Doctrine_Collection('Evaluation');
$ret->fromArray($all);
```

which successfully populated a collection of "Evaluations", but I also need the "User" associated with each evaluation.  The information I need is already in the resultset, but the collection does not automatically create the User object for each Evaluation object.

Then in the view I refer to the relation to print the name of the user, and Doctrine performs a large amount of queries that are not really necesary.

I know there are several ways of avoiding that, but the more natural way (I think) is through the population of the related objects and then accessing them the regular way.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to iterate the resultset creating a "User" object myself before feeding it into `Evaluation::fromArray()`:

Here's how:

```
$q->execute($params);
$all = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
Utilities::array2table($all);   // here I print the raw PDO resultset to debug it

foreach($all as $k => $v){
    $u = new User();
    $u->fromArray($v);
    $all[$k]['User'] = $u;
    // Create a Doctrine "User" and append it to the resultset
}

// Now create the evaluations just like I was before:

$ret = new Doctrine_Collection('Evaluation');
$ret->fromArray($all);
return $ret;
```